# Change of hands during heirship in Islamic economics

Tags: riba, money, banking

I recently learnt (from sources like [ustad Zaid Patel's course in Hindi/Urdu](https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjc7oSoRGqpFc2O0LN7eoP00fRdVEZ03V) and [Sheikh Bilal in English](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9_MMiqoJAds)) that if a person's income is haram or includes haram, it becomes halal for the other person who exchanges it for an economic activity like selling him something and taking his money in return. In short, haram money becomes halal with the change of hands.

And I also learnt that this doesn't work while gifting someone, haram money won't become halal upon gift transfer.

My question is about the transfer when money/properties are transferred during wirasat/heirship from a person to his various family members. Does this kind of transfer convert haram into halal?

Comment: Please share your source of the change of hands claims you are referring to. As the topic is discussed a basis for a discussion is necessary. In any cases there are three views either accepting the change to make the wealth halal for the receiving person, or Haram (especially if he knows the source is Haram) or distinguishing between what is halal and what part is Haram.

Comment: Thank you, added in question.